# Facebook: get app access token using getAccessToken method

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

On facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/) page, there is written:

Facebook::getAccessToken()

Get the current access token being used by the SDK. This may be a user access token or an application access token. See the permissions page for more information on access tokens.

But there is no explanation how to force the method to return app token, not the user token. It is not exmplained nor on permission page. 
Cn anybody help, how this method works?

Comment: yeah i was wondering this same thing...did you figure it out?

Comment: Same here, I'm stuck on simply trying to get a status from a facebook page because of not finding any info on how to actually use the access token in the PHP SDK...

Answer (score 0):

The App access_token is usually just `APP_ID|APP_SECRET`. In my code, I tend to just do this:

```
$app_token = APP_ID . '|' . APP_SECRET;
```